# OnClick for Right Drawable in gridview items (EDITED)

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-drawable

How can i perform an Onclick functionality for right drawable?
I have a gridview item list in which i set a right drawable to each item so that when user input something in editText then that right drawable will show in background and that drawable is delete icon so i want to perform onClick listener for that drawable only so that when user taps on that delete drawble then action is performed. I write the following code but its not working

```
keywordslist.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if(event.getRawX() >= (keywordslist.getRight() - keywordslist.getPaddingRight())) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setMessage("Remove " + ((TextView) v).getText().toString() + "?")
                .setNeutralButton("No", null)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        DBkeyword dbkey = new DBkeyword(context);
                        SQLiteDatabase dbw = dbkey.getWritableDatabase();
                        String deleteKeyword = "delete from " + "screenedkeywords" + " where " + "keywords" + " = \"" + ((TextView) v).getText().toString() + "\"";
                        dbw.execSQL(deleteKeyword);
                        dbw.close();
                        DisplayKeywords();

                    }
                });

             return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to notify your adapter that the data has changed.

```
customGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: As i said that the data is adding in the db but its not displaying on screen, notifyDataSetChanged has nothing to do with it

Comment: First thing if your db has update then also you have to update your screenedKeyWords arraylist as any item has been changed in DB. and then if arraylist has changed you have to notify your adapter. Second thing ..Read about notifyDataSetChanged that what it does

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100 % sure, but shouldn't there be a

```
ArrayAdapter.getItemCount()
```

Maybe you didn't change the returning value from 0 to data.size().

Comment: Ok sir lemme try this